# Textview with filling layout capabilities in android

Tags: android, textview

I have an android row layout that contains a `ImageView`(50 X 50 dp) and a `Textview`.I have set the `ImageView` to `alignParentLeft` and the `Textview` to the right to that `ImageView`.I want the `TextView` to use the space below the `ImageView` as well for displaying text.Is there any custom `TextView` class that will allow me to achieve this kind of UI design.

This is the basic xml code..but the Textview here does not occupy the space beneath the ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique added the basic code..please check..

Comment: Try to use Linear layout rather than relative layout. Distribute design weightly and you will get your result

Comment: Do you want the text to be *only* below the image? Or do you want the text to start to the right of the image, and then have text lines take up the full width once it reaches below the image (like a "drop cap")?

Comment: @UsmanKurd Tried that approach..But even  by using that approach..the textview does not occupy the space below the imageview.A white empty band remains beneath the imageview..

Comment: @Karakuri yes I want the text to be start from the right of ImageView and then have the text lines take up the full width..

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but you may want to edit your post with an image of what you are trying to achieve so that others are not confused.

Comment: I did try posting an image showing what i exactly want..but gives me an error that atleast 10 reputation for posting images..

Comment: please make a link of your image and post.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique tried that as well..but still says that 10 rep needed..

Comment: @ShoebSiddique This is the link to the image..

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZyZFjlPWhoPyQXO4VUgT_qFeAYr84R7atzVHWGA0ptuBccH1r

Comment: @Androidsolutions see this link https://github.com/deano2390/flowtextview

Answer (score 0):

Please see this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="New Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please have a look at Karakuri's comment..He has understood my requirement very well.The code you have posted will only align the textview to the bottom of image..but wont take the full width when it comes below the imageview

Comment: Where you want your textview?